# GROUP_CONCAT Extremely slow

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to use group_concat and join tables using this query. However, it is extremely slow, to the extend which is not possible to apply to production.

```
SELECT
    a.id, 
    a.`name`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER BY c.name) AS occasion, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (x.name) ORDER BY x.name) AS katalog, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(z.city_name) ORDER BY z.city_name) AS city_name, 
    a.featured, 
    a.price, 
    a.saleprice, 
    a.view, 
    a.favorite, 
    a.favnumber, 
    a.bestseller, 
    a.stock, 
    a.product_created, 
    a.product_update
FROM product AS a
    LEFT JOIN product_occasion AS b ON a.id = b.product_id
    LEFT JOIN occasion AS c ON b.occasion_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN product_catalog AS k ON a.id = k.product_id
    LEFT JOIN catalog AS x ON k.catalog_id = x.id
    LEFT JOIN product_city AS y ON a.id = y.product_id
    LEFT JOIN city AS z ON y.city_id = z.id
GROUP BY a.id,
    a.name
```

Appreciate if I could get assistance at improving the query.

Thanks

Comment: Aggregate separately in minimal tables set in subqueries then join. PS. Incomplete GROUP BY. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and adjust grouping expression.

Comment: @Akina - It seems like `GROUP BY id,name` is safe (in _this_ case).

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 significant performance improvements to recommend:

**Indexing**

It looks like you have 3 many-to-many mapping tables.  The typical implementation of such has inefficient indexes.  See [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for how to improve their performance.

**Overkill**

It may not be worth having a separate table for `cities`.  Consider simply having `city_name` in `product_city` (and change the indexing).

**Explode-implode**

This is an SQL design anti-pattern.  It involves joining lots of stuff together, producing lots of intermediate rows, only to then spend a lot of time collapsing down (via `GROUP BY`) to roughly what you started with.

Your example is a very clean one.  Instead of

```
 SELECT
         GROUP_CONCAT(c...)
     LEFT JOIN c
```

do

```
 SELECT
         ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...) FROM c WHERE ... )
```

Ditto for the other two.

Then, the `GROUP BY a.id, a.name` can be eliminated!

Comment: Thanks @RickJames Could you please give me an example? SELECT ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...) FROM c WHERE ... ) I tried to user this, but i doesn't work on me.

Comment: @HenryA - I have given several examples here and on stackoverflow.com involving "left join" and "group_concat":  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1766831+left+join+group_concat